# Images not getting uploaded to the server in multipart format

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple images on a PHP server by multipart but everytime getting a bad body content error on the server. Here is my code for a single image upload (even this is not working so far):

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
aDownloader = [[DataDownload alloc] initWithString:URLString];

NSString *boundary = DDPOST_BOUNDARY;
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];

//Append the images to be sent

  //Start The Boundary

            [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@“abcd"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [postData appendData:imgData];

 //End the boundary

            [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Start the connection

 aDownloader.postData = postData

 aDownloader.tag = DTAG_UploadPhotoes;

 [aDownloader start:NOTIFICATION_UploadPhotoes];

  //My DataDownloader class
downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"] 

NSString *contentType = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", DDPOST_BOUNDARY];

[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:self.postData];
 NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one to upload image on php server.

```
NSString *urlString=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.sampleAPI.com"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"getUrl:%@",urlString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"sample.png"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(user_image)]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

         // This will get the NSURLResponse into NSHTTPURLResponse format

         // This will Fetch the status code from NSHTTPURLResponse object
         NSDictionary *cmsResult =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

         NSLog(@"responce of Registration: %@", cmsResult);

         if (cmsResult.count>0)
         {
             if ([delegate respondsToSelector:didSubmitDataSuccess])
             {
                 [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:didSubmitDataSuccess withObject:cmsResult  waitUntilDone:YES];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if ([delegate respondsToSelector:didFail])
             {
                 [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:didFail withObject:cmsResult waitUntilDone:YES];
             }
         }
         //Just to make sure, it works or not
     }];
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying...Could you please tell...what is "delegate" in your code?...Its throwing me error there

Comment: kayosysTest Mohali: Hello, using delegate we just handle fail and success result. Instead of you can use your condition for success and fail.

Comment: kayosysTest Mohali:I guess you got your solution but Marking an answer with a 'check mark' is expected StackOverflow behavior. If the provided answer does not meet your needs, then provide a comment to the answer

Comment: Avinash I have accepted your answer but my reputation points are not enough to display my vote...

Comment: I am getting this error now: {
    errors = "Image You are not allowed to upload \"\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png";
}       Earlier it was working fine, dont know what happend

Comment: kayosysTest Mohali: What image type you uploaded?

Comment: With the demo project with which I tried out your solution I was uploading png images, right now in the main project no matter what type of image I am uploading its throwing me the same error. I changed this line: [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(user_image)]] everytime according to my image type.

Comment: I am fetching the images either from camera or image library.